# When using GetKeyState in an if statement it is skipping the condition

Tags: c++, windows

I have a bit of code which is supposed to check if you clicked in a certain area in the console, if so it will output `You clicked in the area` I have made the part that checks if your cursor is in the right area but the part that checks if you clicked is ignoring the condition. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

bool clicked = false;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000) //If left mouse button is clicked
        {
            clicked = true;
        }
        POINT point;
        if (GetCursorPos(&point)) {

        }
        if (point.x < 860 && point.x > 260 && point.y < 534 && point.y > 275 && clicked == true) 
        {//if the mouse button is clicked in the specified area
            cout << "You clicked in the area" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What values did you see when you ran this in the debugger ?

Comment: well whenever i hover over the specified area it says you clicked even though I never did

Comment: You have several ifs in your code, when do you want which to act? Why is one of them empty?

Comment: Does that happen before or after you clicked the first time?

Comment: What happens if you do `clicked = false;` after the first output? (I.e. just before the break).

Comment: Shouldn't the statement be **if ((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)** ? Is this the same?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk yes

Comment: @Yunnosch I explained the if's

Comment: Can you try deleting if statements except the first one ? and putting *cout part* to inside of it? Does it give the same result or working correctly?

Comment: I  tried you code and it does not behave as described. Please double-check that the shown code is a [mre] to demonstrate what you describe. I guess there might be a difference concerning the `break`. Also, please answer comment by Sid. Debug by eiher using a debugger or outputting the coordinates. I think they are not as you expect them to be.

Comment: What happens if you put an unconditional `clicked=false;` at the end of and inside the loop?

Comment: I do not think that you explained the ifs. At least the explanation of the if with the empty body is not satisfying...

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk yes it does

Comment: @Yunnosch when I set clicked to false at the end outside the loop it works now thank you as to the other if, i'm not exactly sure what it does but without it I get an error

Comment: Related: [GetKeyState function not working when checking if left mouse button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59923765/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset your `clicked`.
There are more problems in your code, which probably will trip you up ...

But as you already confirmed, resetting the flag at the end of the loop helps.

```
while (true)
{
    // your loop code

    // reset flag
    clicked= false;
}
```

Comment: What might these other problems be?

Comment: The first few I noticed I turned into comments on your question.